# Classic mathematics books by British mathematicians

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

Having recently read a review that expounded on the rigour and depth of books by 'earlier' British mathematicians (mainly analysts) I would like to know more. My own research yielded the following tentative list, which I believe to be relatively incomplete and shallow:

- G. H. Hardy, *A Course of Pure Mathematics*.
- G. H. Hardy, E. M. Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*.
- E. C. Titchmarsh, *The Theory of Functions*.
- E. W. Hobson, *The Theory of Functions of a Real Variable and the Theory of Fourier's Series (2 vols.)*.
- E. T. Copson, *An Introduction to the Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable*.
- Alfred North Whitehead, Bertrand Russell, *Principia Mathematica*.
- G. S. Carr, *Synopsis of Pure Mathematics (2 vols.)*.

I'm certain that there are many other classics, concentrated most probably in the early or mid-20th century. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis.

Comment: Do all the authors have to be British? The book *Inequalities* by Hardy, Littlewood and Pólya, for example, is also a classic, 2/3 of the authors of which are British.  I can also suggest Baker's *Transcendental Number Theory* and Ingham's *Distribution of Prime Numbers*, although of course it depends on exactly what you call a "classic".

Comment: Especially influential were Whittaker's 1902 (1st edition) **A Course of Modern Analysis** (Watson joined as co-author with the 1915 2nd edition) and Bromwich's 1908 (1st edition) **An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series**. *(moments later)* I see that @lhf has cited Whittaker also.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen they don't have to all be British authors I guess. I don't mind so long as they came from the intellectual ferment of Hardy, Littlewood etc.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro your knowledge about mathematics literature never ceases to amaze me, how many books do you own?

Comment: As a very rough guess, maybe around 1500 math books, plus or minus 2 or 3 hundred. Keep in mind that I've been accumulating them for about 45 years. On the other hand, the number of journal pages that I've photocopied over the last 25-30 years is probably some kind of record (a number well into 6 digits). See my comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383168/where-can-i-learn-more-about-commutative-hyperoperations), for instance. And in the past 10 years I've digitally accumulated from google-books nearly 1000 19th century books and full runs of 25 to 30 19th century journals.

Comment: This seems to be a list-based question. Perhaps it would be useful to have a meta discussion to decide whether list questions should be on-topic?

Comment: Basically you want http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/recreational-mathematics/series/cambridge-mathematical-library?layout=listing&pageSize=&sortOrder=pubAndEbookPrice_N%5Basc%5D

Comment: @MariusKempe Thank you, that was a nice find!

Comment: @DaveLRenfro On an unrelated note, could you recommend me the best recreational mathematics journal? I'd really appreciate it. I know the Mathematical Gazette is one, what are some notable others? Thank you.

Comment: "Best" is highly subjective, and even for me it would likely be different this morning as compared to last week. That said, MathProPress has a lengthy list [here](http://www.mathpropress.com/elementaryJournals.html), and I compiled my own list in [this 24 September 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3974282). **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** That said, among the best known *recreational math journals* (which I don't consider Math. Gazette to be -- it's mainly an elementary journal for teachers of the first few years of college math) is [The Fibonacci Quarterly](http://www.fq.math.ca/) and [Journal of Recreational Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Recreational_Mathematics).

Answer (score 1):

You really want a list of British early 20th century books in mathematics?
What for? It will be too long, of course.

Two classical books by Titchmarsh are missing in your list:

Riemann zeta function,

and Eigenfunction expansions associated with second-order differential equations.

Another notable omission in your list are the books of Watson,

Bessel functions, and

Course of Modern Analysis, joint with Whittaker.

The last book deserves an entry in the Guinnes book of records as a textbook
continuously in print for more than 100 years. Perhaps unique in all sciences.